# A form that posts values and then shows itself again in Codeigniter without AJAX

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I have a CodeIgniter form, that looks a bit like this in code:

```php
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/updateperson', array("id" => "updateform")); ?>
  <input placeholder="First name" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?= form_prep($person->fname) ?>" />
  <?= form_submit("save", "Save"); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I want to be able to hit Save, and have it go to a Controller which will save the uploaded data to the database, and then forward me on to the Controller that showed the form in the first place, which will return me to that same page, displaying the updated details.

I'm currently doing it with limited success with a `redirect` call in the upload controller, so CodeIgniter just routes the request as normal to the original Controller that reads from the database and displays the form as in the first place. This sort of works.

However, there's a bug: while it *does* update the data in the database, and it shows me the original form, it shows me the previous values! These can be cleared by hitting F5 or going into the page again, but looks bad.

Is there a better way to do this? I'd think about using `set_form`, but that's only designed for when validation fails, apparently?

Comment: I have done similar things before and it works. Are you sure that $person->fname contains the updated data and you are not somehow populating "$person->fname" before updating the database (I know this is particularly unlikely in your case but worth a check)

Comment: Hmmm I don't think so; might that survive through the `redirect` call?

Comment: No...but maybe ur doing something after the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `redirect` after the form submission you need to store all data you need to keep to be visible in the next page,

you can store data in `Session, Cookie, Url or HTML5 local and/or session storage`

As you preferr :)

Comment: Is that even if the page I'm redirecting to has a controller behind it that should read all the new info out of the DB?

Comment: Sorry, didn't meant to sound ungrateful - thanks for the reply!